# C reading and printing numbers

Tags: c, printf

I'm having a bit of troubles with the following code.
I am trying to get the following output when the input would be: 2 3 5

Output: '3 5 Som: 8'

I can't seem to manage to get the 3 and the 5 in front of 'Som: 8'.

I am fairly new to C programming and would appreciate getting some help on this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
int N, sum = 0, c, array[100];

   scanf("%d", &N);

   for (c = 0; c < N; c++)
   {
      scanf("%d", &array[c]);
      sum = sum + array[c];
   }

   printf("Som: %d",sum);

   return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &array[c]); printf("%d ", array[c]);`

Comment: Did you consider adding a `printf` loop for the array before your output line?

Comment: I just added 'printf("%d ", array[c]);' in the forloop. Seems to work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Piece of cake:
Add

```
printf("%d ",array[c]);
```

inside another `for` loop which is identical to the `for` loop that you have in your code,somewhere after the last`printf`.